# In custom iOS keyboard detect the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, keyboard, ios-extensions

How to detect in which app my custom keyboard used and show different button?
E.g. in Twitter I would add @ to string I post into input field and in Reddit /r/

Comment: Like Schemetrical said, you can't determine the app you're in (at least, you're not *supposed* to be able to be, and probably any answer posted here would be considered a loophole and be fixed by Apple), but you *can* know that you're in a Twitter style text field, and respond appropriately, which might be better than knowing the app, since there are built in APIs to post to Twitter that can be used from any app.

Comment: @BenPious thanks for inspirations! I appreciate any clues about "Twitter style text field"

Comment: You have access in the API to an object (I forget which) which implements this protocol: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/

Comment: UIKeyboardTypeDefault,
  UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,
  UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,
  UIKeyboardTypeURL,
  UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,
  UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,
  UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,
  UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,
  UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,
  UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,
  UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch,
  UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable

Comment: @BenPious how do you this is that violate developer guidelines or not?

Comment: @BenPious I have twitter style text field in Instagram, Slack and other apps. Eh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: See above. Things have changed.

This is not possible. **An extension runs sandboxed** and is only fed information from the API and cannot access anything else. The keyboard can only receive text context changes and activate/deactivate calls. Being able to detect an app lies outside of the extension sandbox and therefore is impossible.

Comment: This is just wrong. It is possible to get the host's app bundle identified with the @halfer answer above.

Comment: @GrantOganyan this is probably out of date, I’ll delete

Comment: Looks like I cant. Hopefully people read above.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible through following code. As you'll get bundle identifier of the app where you're using your custom keyboard.

**Swift**

```
    let hostBundleID = self.parentViewController!.valueForKey("_hostBundleID")
    let currentHostBundleID = String(hostBundleID)
    print(currentHostBundleID);
```

From bundle identifier you can find app name easily.

Comment: is this allowed by apple?... as in would this cause an app extension to be rejected?

Comment: @WillVonUllrich One of my app approved by Apple which has the same implementation. So hope it works in your case too.

Comment: Is there any API to get app details from bundle id?

Comment: This has unfortunately stopped working in iOS 16.