# How does Google's custom iOS keyboard, Gboard, programmatically dismiss the frontmost app?

Tags: ios, ios-keyboard-extension

Google's custom iOS app, [Gboard](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gboard-a-new-keyboard-from-google/id1091700242?mt=8), has an interesting feature that can't be accomplished using public APIs for in the iOS SDK (as of iOS 10).  **I'd like to know exactly how Google accomplishes the task of programmatically popping back one app in the App Switching stack in Gboard.**

Custom iOS keyboards have two major components: the container app and the keyboard app extension.  The keyboard app extension runs in a separate OS process that is started up whenever a user is in any app on their phone that requires text input.

These are the approximate steps that can be followed, using Gboard, to see the effect of programmatically returning to a previous app:

1. A user starts the Apple [Messages](https://support.apple.com/explore/messages) app on their iPhone and taps a text field to begin entering text.
2. The Gboard keyboard extension is launched and the users sees the Gboard custom keyboard (while they are still in the Apple Messages app).
3. The user taps the microphone key inside the Gboard keyboard extension to do voice-to-text input.
4. Gboard uses a [custom url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) to launch the Gboard container app.  The Gboard keyboard and Apple messages app are pushed down one layer in the App stack and the Gboard container app is now the frontmost app in the App stack.  The Gboard container app uses the microphone to listen to the user's speech and translates it into text which it places onto the screen.
5. The user taps the "Done" button when they are satisfied with the text input they see on the screen.
6. **This is where the magic happens… as the text input screen is dismissed, the Gboard container app is also dismissed automatically.  The Gboard container app goes away and is replaced by the Apple Messages app (sometimes the Gboard keyboard extension process is still alive, sometimes it is relaunched, and sometimes it needs to be re-launched manually by tapping inside a text field.) . How does Google accomplish this?**
7. Finally, the user sees the text that was just translated inserted automatically inside the text input field.  Presumably Google accomplishes this by [sharing data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) between the Gboard container app and the keyboard extension.

I would assume that Google is using private APIs by exploring the status bar's view hierarchy using Objective-C runtime introspection and somehow synthesizing tap events or calling an exposed target / action.  I've explored this a very little and have been able to find interesting UIView subclasses inside the status bar, like [UIStatusBarBreadcrumbItemView](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStatusBarBreadcrumbItemView.h) which contains an array of [UISystemNavigationAction](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UISystemNavigationAction.h)s.  I'm continuing to explore these classes in the hope that I can find some way of replicating the user interaction.

I understand that using private APIs is a good way to get your app submission rejected from the App Store - this isn't a concern that I'd like to be addressed in the answer.  I'm looking primarily for specific answers about how exactly how Google accomplishes the task of programmatically popping back one app in the App Switching stack in Gboard.

Comment: Does this happen with any arbitrary application? In case of the system Messages app, it is quite easy - there is a scheme to launch it : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html. If this works also with other apps (especially less popular ones) it would be indeed curious.

Comment: @Losiowaty It appears to happen with any arbitrary application.

Comment: About the step 4, I can't open the container/host app, how do you do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

## Your guess is correct — Gboard is using private API to do it.

*… though not through exploring view hierarchy or event injection.*

When the voice-to-text action is done, we can check the syslog from Xcode or Console that it calls the `-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]` method. So I've reverse-engineered the Gboard app and look for the stack trace related to this.

Climbing up the call stack we can find the `-[GKBVoiceRecognitionViewController navigateBackToPreviousApp]` method, and…

[image]

[…`_systemNavigationAction`?](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/995b3bb9011192afcd70eed8fb73f1b6688c52f2/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIApplication.h#L168) Yep, definitely private API.

Since `class_getInstanceVariable` is a public API and `"_systemNavigationAction"` is a string literal, the automatic checker is not able to note the private API usage, and the human reviewers probably don't see anything wrong with the "jump back to the previous app" behavior. Or probably because they are Google and you are not…

---

The actual code that performs the "jump back to previous app" action is like this:

```
@import UIKit;
@import ObjectiveC.runtime;

@interface UISystemNavigationAction : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nonnull) NSArray<NSNumber*>* destinations;
-(BOOL)sendResponseForDestination:(NSUInteger)destination;
@end

inline BOOL jumpBackToPreviousApp() {
    Ivar sysNavIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(UIApplication.class, "_systemNavigationAction");
    UIApplication* app = UIApplication.sharedApplication;
    UISystemNavigationAction* action = object_getIvar(app, sysNavIvar);
    if (!action) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSUInteger destination = action.destinations.firstObject.unsignedIntegerValue;
    return [action sendResponseForDestination:destination];
}
```

In particular, the `-sendResponseForDestination:` method performs the actual "go back" action.

(Since the API is undocumented, Gboard is actually using the API *incorrectly*. They used the wrong signature `-(void)sendResponseForDestination:(id)destination`. But it happens that all numbers other than `1` will work the same, so the Google developers are lucky this time)

Comment: Great answer! I doubt that Google intentionally tried to hide this, though.
I guess that private apis are permitted to some extent between the big corporations.

Comment: Simply impressive! Thank you for shedding light on this. Just to make sure that I get it right: is the code provided supposed to work us as well or is it still private API?

Comment: @AhmetAkkök It's still private to Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is unfair competition though. Shame on Apple. Apple stood up it's developers and provided private API access to their biggest competitor.

Comment: @AhmetAkkök I don't believe Apple specifically allowed Google to violate rule 2.5.1, otherwise Google could simply use the [`_systemNavigationAction`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/995b3bb/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIApplication.h#L609) *method*, more convenient. I believe it is just ignorance of the App Store human reviewers.

Comment: @kennytm So that means we are able (not me obviously, you are) violate rule 2.5.1 as well? I need the exact same speech-to-text functionality. I would let App Store review team to judge.

Comment: @AhmetAkkök Haha. You could try. Apple has right to remove the app from App Store anytime because you did violate the review guideline (look at what they did with Dash (though not 2.5.1-relevant)). It's basically a risk/return tradeoff judgment on the dev side.

Comment: @kennytm  I think I will give it shot. I appreciate very much if you can add the Swift version of the solution...

Comment: @AhmetAkkök I suggest you just create an [Objective-C bridge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift/24005242#24005242). Pure Swift is okay, but because of all those unsafe-pointer manipulation the code is going to be extremely ugly.

Comment: @kennytm I will try

Comment: @kennytm, do you know how to implement the step 4? That means opening the container app from keyboard extension, thanks.

Comment: @Changwei https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495362/launch-containing-app-from-ios8-custom-keyboard

Comment: @kennytm thank you for your reply, but I can't open the container app via Custom URL Scheme. Now, I try to use Universal Links to open the container app and it works. Thank you again.

Comment: Swift version would be highly appreciated. Currently, after successful bridging, build fails is I call "jumpBackToPreviousApp()" from a ViewController with error: ":-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: I hate that Apple actually have these private apis that sometimes are ok and sometimes are very much not ok to use.

Comment: This private API-based solution no longer works in iOS 17.

Comment: Unfortunately, we will get nil using _systemNavigationAction method in iOS 17.0 :(

Comment: + same problem here for iOS 17

Comment: i am also using this method, anybody got solution for iOS 17 ?

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: this hack stopped working on iOS 17, Gboard also can't do it anymore

---

**Swift version** of @kennytm answer:

```
@objc private protocol PrivateSelectors: NSObjectProtocol {
    var destinations: [NSNumber] { get }
    func sendResponseForDestination(_ destination: NSNumber)
}

func jumpBackToPreviousApp() -> Bool {
    guard
        let sysNavIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(UIApplication.self, "_systemNavigationAction"),
        let action = object_getIvar(UIApplication.shared, sysNavIvar) as? NSObject,
        let destinations = action.perform(#selector(getter: PrivateSelectors.destinations)).takeUnretainedValue() as? [NSNumber],
        let firstDestination = destinations.first
    else {
        return false
    }
    action.perform(#selector(PrivateSelectors.sendResponseForDestination), with: firstDestination)
    return true
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately stopped working in iOS 17. object_getIvar now returns `nil`.

Comment: @DanielSaidi can Google keyboard still do it?

Comment: Not the last time I checked, using the last public beta.

Comment: @PhilDukhov Nop. Gboard is same. not works

Comment: Are there other feasible ways to achieve the same effect in iOS 17?

Comment: any update in iOS 17 guys?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS17: Use a private API to figure out what app is currently open whenever the keyboard appears, and store that in `sharedDefaults`. Then use that stored `bundle_id` to open it again from the keyboard app. Probably going to get your app rejected though!

Find out current open app using [KeyboardKit](https://keyboardkit.github.io/KeyboardKit/documentation/keyboardkit/keyboardinputviewcontroller/hostbundleid) or [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407921/in-custom-ios-keyboard-detect-the-app)

Store bundleID on keyboard appear, or when they press the mic button:

```
    .onAppear() {
        sharedDefaults?.set(bundleId, forKey: "last_app_bundle_id")
    }
```

Open `last_app_bundle_id` using `LSApplicationWorkspace` from your keyboard app if iOS17, else use Phil's code:

```
static func jumpBackToPreviousApp() -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        let sharedDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.lexia")
        let lastAppBundleId = sharedDefaults?.string(forKey: "last_app_bundle_id")
        guard let obj = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace") as? NSObject else { return false }
        let workspace = obj.perform(Selector(("defaultWorkspace")))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? NSObject
        let open = workspace?.perform(Selector(("openApplicationWithBundleID:")), with: lastAppBundleId) != nil
        return open
    } else {
        guard
            let sysNavIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(UIApplication.self, "_systemNavigationAction"),
            let action = object_getIvar(UIApplication.shared, sysNavIvar) as? NSObject,
            let destinations = action.perform(#selector(getter: PrivateSelectors.destinations)).takeUnretainedValue() as? [NSNumber],
            let firstDestination = destinations.first
        else {
            return false
        }
        action.perform(#selector(PrivateSelectors.sendResponseForDestination), with: firstDestination)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... It works. But, as you know, hostBundleId of KeyboardKit is really dangerous code because it is using private APIs and XPC framework as low-level intercommunication framework.