# Go to previous app in iOS ( like GBoard do )

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, gboard

Can't figure out how Google did this. But when you use GBoard (Google's custom keyboard), they have dictation function inside and if you use it, keyboard open GBoard app which listening (because custom keyboards have no access to microphone) and after listening it goes back to previous app where did you call dictation function from. How is it possible? It works even with empty app build from template so I'm pretty sure it isnt working over some framework like FB Links etc.

Any ideas? Private API?

Comment: I din't quite get it. Do want to open another app from your app?

Comment: Some app opens my app via URL Scheme and after some actions inside my app I want to go back to previous app without user interaction. You can download google's keyboard Gboard to see they doing this with any app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495362/launch-containing-app-from-ios8-custom-keyboard

Comment: This is how to open containing app from custom keyboard, my question isnt about that. My question is how to get back to app which opens containing app before.

Comment: Flow looks like this: Whatsapp with my custom keyboard opens my custom keyboard containing app and then my containing app goes back to whats app with my custom keyboard presented.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516357/how-does-googles-custom-ios-keyboard-gboard-programtically-dismiss-the-frontm